# Sending very large Object over the network with RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I have to send a very large object of size > 100 MB over RMI

Which of these two approaches is best one ?

1. Sending the Remote Object in RMI call

or

2. Sending the byte array of the object in RMI call & re-creating the object at receiver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's hardly any difference, except that the second way you give yourself extra work and another source of error. The 100MB of data will totally dominate the serialization overhead.